# Magento 2.2.8 Upgrade Redis Expects string object given

Tags: magento2, upgrade, redis

I have just upgraded from Magento `2.1.9` to `2.2.8`.

Redis was previously working fine, however, when I activate it now through my env.php file, I am receiving this error.

> Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
>   /http/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php
>   on line 1188","1":"1 substr() called at
>   [vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php:1188]

What could be causing this?

When i comment out the Redis configuration in the env.php file, the site works okay but it will not show any updates.

I have tried `rm -rf var/generation var/di` and all other normally necessary commands but none of them seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generation directory is no longer in var. There seems to be something wrong with your env configuration or with data already cached in Redis. To configure env correctly use

```
bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis --page-cache=redis
```

To clear existing redis cache use `flushall` inside `redis-cli`